# How to create clean table structure for posting questions in stackoverflow

Tags: datatable, nlp-question-answering

I am trying to understand as to how to post clean data tables in stackoverflow to ask questions. When I try to copy questions from Excel I find it difficult to maintain clean structure and when I try to use the code sample block too I find it difficult to arrange the data when there are more than 5 columns and multiple rows.

Comment: https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Martheen.. The link  https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/  helps convert excel and csv file data to proper table structure and it can be copied onto  stackoverflow platform for asking questions!